# Counting occurrences of factor by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm dealing with some dplyr issues. I would like to create a new variable which is the frequency of a factor's level, but I would like to do it by group. Here's an extract of my data:

```
head(Dataset)
Code_PR   Code_SP  Status_SP
  PR1        SP1       0
  PR1        SP2       0
  PR1        SP3       1
  PR2        SP1       0
  PR2        SP2       1
```

I would like to get a result like this:

```
Code_PR   Count  Ratio
  PR1      3       1/3 
  PR2      2       1/2
```

I tried the following code, and modified it but I always get the same error:

```
RatioAb <-  Database_V2  %>%
group_by(CodePR, StatutSP) %>%
summarize(
n=n(),
Ratio =count(StatutSP, '1')/count(StatutSP)
)
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error:
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class 
"logical"
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dataset %>% 
  group_by(Code_PR) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n(), Ratio = paste0(sum(Status_SP),"/",n()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Code_PR) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n()
            , Ratio = mean(Status_SP))

## A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Code_PR Count Ratio
#   <chr>   <int> <dbl>
# 1 PR1         3 0.333
# 2 PR2         2 0.500
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I still get an error doing this too "Error : This function should not be called directly"

Comment: Which function is the error referring to? Must be a problem with your R environment.

Comment: Exactly, I restarted my R session, but now I only get NA : 'In mean.default(StatutSP) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA'

Comment: Oh, yeah, you can't take the mean of a non-numeric (or logical) vector. Find a way to make it numeric before taking the mean.

Comment: @Hack-R I still get weird results

Comment: @Layale Oh ok in that case please provide the error or example

Comment: if numbers are encoded a factors you'll need to use `as.numeric(as.character(x))` on them, not just `as.numeric`